# Got UndeclaredThrowableException at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.Open when trying to open an excel workbook

Tags: java, excel

I have a feature in a plugin which exports some checklist items into Excel file. Before, everything worked fine, but since a few days ago i got an error with $Proxy10.Open() when trying to open the excel workbook. I don't know if this information is relevant, but i can reproduce this problem only on a few computers, on some of them i can reproduce it only if iam connecting to it remotely.

The error is:

```
    java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.Open(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:157)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.Factory$ProxyObject2.invoke(Factory.java:93)
... 5 more
```

This is how i initialize COM subsystem:

```
Ole32.INSTANCE.CoInitializeEx(Pointer.NULL, Ole32.COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
facade.comFactory = new Factory();
```

This is how I am initializing the excel application:

```
ComExcel_Application excel = facade.comFactory.createObject(ComExcel_Application.class);
facade.excelApp = excel.queryInterface(Application.class);
facade.excelApp.setVisible(true);
System.out.println("Using Excel version: " + facade.excelApp.getVersion());
```

And this is where the exception is thrown:

```
Workbook myWorkbook = excelApp.getWorkbooks().Open(fullName.toString());
```

I want to ask what is the root problem of this error and any hints are welcomed. I tried to find any related questions or errors, but nothing found.

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow` you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then edit your post

Comment: @ButiriDan thank you for drawing my attention to edit the post. Hope i have edited it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the point where the Factory() is initialized for COM object creation. com.sun.jna.platform.win32.COM.util.Factory uses a thread to run the calls and this thread imposes an upper limit of execution time which is by default 5000ms. So I have extended the thread’s execution time to 15000ms.

```
facade.comFactory = new Factory(new ComThread("COM Thread", 15000, new  
                  Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() { 
                        @Override 
                        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) { 
                            // do something intelligent 
                        } 
                    }));
```